# Pangram code - Unable to understand problem in my written code - always returns false

Tags: javascript

```
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
function isPangram (inputPangram) {
    for (x of alphabet) {
       if (!inputPangram.includes(x)){
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note:
This is a pangram:
"Brown jars prevented the mixture from freezing too quickly"

but if given to function it returns false, I am unable to understand the problem in my code. I am stuck on this, thankyou for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking for lower case letters, so you miss the `B` in `"Brown"`. Make your input lower case using [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) such that you're only looking for lower case letters:

```js
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function isPangram(inputPangram) {
  const lowerCaseInput = inputPangram.toLowerCase();
  for (const x of alphabet) {
    if (!lowerCaseInput.includes(x)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isPangram("Brown jars prevented the mixture from freezing too quickly"));
```

Comment: I think you meant make the *input* lowercase - `alphabet` is already lowercase.

Comment: @Mitya oh yes, you're right! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you. Got it. I was stuck on this for like an hour :D